# Exceeded Your Daily Request

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have just got a new api key for doing map requests, but today I am getting the error:

callback=mr.maps.init:43 Geocoding Service: You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.  For more information on usage limits and the Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

I am one of 2 visitors to the site running on a local server. and we have not refreshed the page 25,000 times to exceed the request limit.

Wondering why I am getting this error, and if I can check the number of requests my api key has made.

Comment: You'll have to post some code so we can see if something might be going on under the hood. Are you calling in a loop/making calls from functions that might be getting executed multiple times?

Comment: Although Ben's suspicion is probably accurate, it's also possible someone stole your api key.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different key and see if issue reproduces.

In case it does it means you have a code issue.

If it doesn't most likely your key was stolen.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might have some sort of looping issue. If you're using github make sure your api key isn't uploaded on your repository